# What is the best to use with developing Windows phone 8, SQL Server Express or SQL Server Compact or SQLite?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I want to build a new windows phone application that connect with local database, I want to write some complicated SQL to retrieve data.

What is the best to use with Windows phone 8.1, SQL Server Express, SQL Server Compact edition, or SQLite?

Pros and cons please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you meant what to use for a local DB on windows phone, [Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com/) is one of the best options that I have used so far.

Comment: Yes, but I want to use some complicated sql, does Sterling will meet that?

Comment: How much complicated? Check with the codeplex site..

Comment: Complicated but sqlite work with it

Comment: I sure it will work with sterling then :D. To be sure, create a project and test them out before stating the actual work that will also give you a hands on on Sterling!

Comment: After trying several solutions for persistance, I agree that Sterling is really a great solution. Actually it was far easier to set up than the others. And seems like it's faster too, so you should definitely give it a try.